# Double Click in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 Solution Explorer Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, explorer, solution

Until quite recently it was possible to click on a method in the VS 2013 Solution Explorer and have the method appear in the code window. That does not appear to be working anymore. Any idea of how to enable this functionality? It was quite useful. For example, in the Solution Explorer view below, clicking on either addBlanks or formatSql would move the code window to the method in question.

It turns out that I have more information about this problem. I completely uninstalled VS 2013 Pro and reinstalled it. Somewhat predictably the problem went away... However, I was getting an error message about the NuGet package manager not being properly installed. To fix this I removed and reinstalled the NuGet package manager. That did resolve the NuGet error message, but the problem with clicking on methods in the Solution Explorer came back. Finally I removed and reinstalled VS 2013 Pro yet another time and now clicking on methods in the Solution Explorer works correctly.

Somehow the original problem reflects some combination of VS 2013 Pro, NuGet, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to quickly display a source code file. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express Update 3.

It might make a difference to highlight/activate the right-most code preview symbol in the `Solution Explorer` panel:

[image]

It is located to the right of the properties screw-wrench symbol.

If this symbol is active, a single click on a file name is sufficient to get the file displayed in the code view. The same applies to methods. Double-click also works, when the preview symbol is not highlighted.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kemper. However, I have never had a problem viewing files by clicking on them in VS 2013 Pro. The problem was with moving around inside a file by clicking on methods in the Solution Explorer on the left. This did not work (but now does, see my notes above).

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in Visual Studio 2013 Pro Update 3 (and perhaps other versions). Microsoft recognized this bug and has fixed it in VS 2013 Pro Update 4. See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1001072/double-click-in-visual-studio-2013-update-3-solution-explorer-not-working for a discussion and Microsoft's resolution.